# Diagram relating all the families of sets?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, definition

There are lots of important definitions of families of sets (e.g., algebra, ring, $\pi$-system, Dynkin system). I'm looking for some nice diagrams or tables that organize these definitions. The closest examples I've found on the web are [this table](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Family_of_sets#Special_types_of_set_families) (which tabulates properties of different systems, but not necessarily the defining properties, and it doesn't indicate the relationships between systems), and [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/LaTeX1_Kopie.png) diagram (which is closer to what I want, but in German, and it only includes a few structures).

Does anyone know of more good diagrams or tables that would help?

Comment: I wonder how chat gpt would fare.